# Windows 10 on Dell precision m65

Tags: hard-drive, windows-xp, dell-precision, windows-10-v1607

I have a Dell Drecision M65 with Windows XP. Its specs are:

- Processor: Intel Yonah Core Duo T2400 (1.83GHz/2MB L2 Cache)
- OS: Microsoft Windows XP Professional
- Hard Drive: 80 GB SATA @ 5400RPM
- Screen: 15.4″ WSXGA Widescreen (1680×1050)
- Graphics: NVIDIA Quadro FX 350M 512 MB TurboCache (256+256) OpenGL
- RAM: 2 GB DDR2 SDRAM @667 MHz (2 x 1GB)
- Optical Drive: 8x CD/DVD burner (DVD+/-RW) w/Double Layer Support
- Battery: 6-cell lithium ion
- Wireless: Intel PRO/Wireless 3945 802.11 b/g Mini Card (54 Mbps)

Will windows 10 run smoothly with this hardware? Considering the hdd space needed since the Dell only has an 80 GB hdd.

Comment: A clean install should be fine. Wouldn't say it will run smoothly, windows may run fine, but applications will suffer.

Comment: It will have poor performance on that hardware.

Comment: so you suggest to leave xp on it? or maybe to try with 7?

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this response on a:

- Dell Precision M65
- Windows 10 Home 64 bit version 1909
- Core 2 Duo T7200 @ 2.00 GHz
- 4.00 GHz DDR2 @ 333 MHz
- 120 GB Kingston SSD
- 802.11 n wifi dongle

This laptop is old but very functional and is not bogged down when using youtube or reddit. I have newer devices here but I still love this pc and find it easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the system requirements it's likely that there will be somewhat poor performance using that hardware. You would need to specify if your computer is 32 or 64 bit, but you do meet the system requirements on both, if barely.

At this point if you can afford one, buy a brand new workstation. Your current one is at least 10 years old at this point and the performance will be much better on a new laptop than on your current one.

But yes you could get a clean install of Windows 10 on your computer, but get a new one if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed Windows 10 32bit on a similar specification Fujitsu laptop.

- Core2 Duo T5450 1.67GHz
- 2GB RAM
- 160GB 5400rpm disk

Windows 10 takes about 10GB before anything else is installed.

I had to get a Windows 10 driver from Realtek for the Audio. Vista drivers which were available from the manufacturer also work.
I use a 802.11n dongle rather than the built-in 802.11g.

It's OK for web browsing. The performance is better than Vista and probably than Windows 7.

I wouldn't have done this if I'd had to pay for Windows 10, as you would need to now.

Comment: Honestly i'm installing Windows 10 mainly for Office 2016, because XP can only have the 2003 version installed and i must run my docs in compatibility mode. So if someone told me that Windows 7 would have better performance with that hardware I would put it right away.

Comment: @andreav94 I've not seen any performance hits going from 7 to 10. 10 is easier on memory - I've got it running on a 1GB tablet. Just go for the cheaper option.